# Meaning of jStatus log values in LSF

Tags: sas, lsf

Am currently trying to decipher the contents of the **lsb.events** log file, as created by Platform Computing "Platform Process Manager" (Flow Manager), version 8.1.

From the various [sources](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/platform-computing-lsf-documentation.html) of documentation I see the following descriptions for the jStatus variable:

- 4=RUN
- 32=JOB_STAT_EXIT
- 64=JOB_STAT_DONE

However in the JOB_STATUS entry, there are also jStatus values of 2 and 192.  **What do these values represent?**

Tagging SAS as this implementation was bundled with it.  As a side point, I observe that in some cases the actual fields in our lsb.events file are not aligned with those that are supposed to appear according to the aforementioned documentation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status 2 represents a job in PSUSP status, which is attained in several ways (for example submitting a job with the -H option to hold it from scheduling).

For 192, the answer is that the job status is a bitfield.  In this case there are 2 bits set:

- 64 = JOB_STAT_DONE
- 128 = JOB_STAT_PDONE

JOB_STAT_PDONE means that the job had a post-execution script defined and it has completed successfully.

The valid values for the job status bits are in the `lsf/lsbatch.h` file shipped with LSF in the include directory: `<LSF_INSTALL_DIR>/<LSF_VERSION>/include/lsf/lsbatch.h`

Answer (score 0):

To expand, with thanks and credit to @Squirrel, the relevant contents of our `C:\LSF_7.0\7.0\include\lsf\lsbatch.h` file were:

```
/**  * \addtogroup job_states job_states  * define job states  */ /*@{*/
#define JOB_STAT_NULL         0x00       /**< State null*/
#define JOB_STAT_PEND         0x01       /**< The job is pending, i.e., it 
                                            * has not been dispatched yet.*/
#define JOB_STAT_PSUSP        0x02       /**< The pending job was suspended by its
                                            * owner or the LSF system administrator.*/
#define JOB_STAT_RUN          0x04       /**< The job is running.*/
#define JOB_STAT_SSUSP        0x08       /**< The running job was suspended 
                                           * by the system because an execution 
                                           * host was overloaded or the queue run 
                                           * window closed. (see \ref lsb_queueinfo, 
                                           * \ref lsb_hostinfo, and lsb.queues.)
                                           */
#define JOB_STAT_USUSP        0x10       /**< The running job was suspended by its 
                                           * owner or the LSF system administrator.*/
#define JOB_STAT_EXIT         0x20       /**< The job has terminated with a non-zero
                                           * status - it may have been aborted due 
                                           * to an error in its execution, or 
                                           * killed by its owner or by the 
                                           * LSF system administrator.*/
#define JOB_STAT_DONE         0x40       /**< The job has terminated with status 0.*/
#define JOB_STAT_PDONE        (0x80)     /**< Post job process done successfully */
#define JOB_STAT_PERR         (0x100)    /**< Post job process has error */
#define JOB_STAT_WAIT         (0x200)    /**< Chunk job waiting its turn to exec */
#define JOB_STAT_RUNKWN       0x8000     /* Flag : Job status is UNKWN caused by 
                                          * losting contact with remote cluster */
#define JOB_STAT_UNKWN        0x10000    /**< The slave batch daemon (sbatchd) on 
                                          * the host on which the job is processed 
                                          * has lost contact with the master batch 
                                          * daemon (mbatchd).*/
```

and again, in decimal:

```
0       JOB_STAT_NULL
1       JOB_STAT_PEND
2       JOB_STAT_PSUSP
4       JOB_STAT_RUN
8       JOB_STAT_SSUSP 
16      JOB_STAT_USUSP 
32      JOB_STAT_EXIT 
64      JOB_STAT_DONE
128     JOB_STAT_PDONE 
256     JOB_STAT_PERR 
512     JOB_STAT_WAIT
32768   JOB_STAT_RUNKWN 
65536   JOB_STAT_UNKWN
```